# Margin Changes in the Table of Contents (memoir class)

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, memoir

The upper margin is supposed to be 1" throughout my document. In the table of contents it changes from 1" to less than 1". How may I make it consistent?

**Note:** I am using the `pwasu.sty` style file from my university. I contacted them regarding this and other issues. Their only response was that if it doesn't meet the requirements then I must change it (no suggestion for resolution).

**My .tex code:**

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag,epsfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\DoubleSpacing
\usepackage{pwasu}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\parskip 7.2pt
\parindent 0.5in

\DoubleSpacing
\begin{document}
\maxtocdepth{subparagraph}
\pagestyle{plain}
\frontmatter
\thetitlepage

% Macro for List of Symbols
\def\listofsymbols{\input{memoir/symbols} \clearpage}
\def\addsymbol #1: #2#3{$#1$ \> \parbox{5.45in}{#2 \dotfill \pageref{#3}}\\}
\def\newnot#1{\label{#1}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% put your abstract here
\asuabstract
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}
This is the abstract.


\newpage
\centering{DEDICATION}
\flushleft{Enter your dedication text here}
\clearpage

\asuacknowledgements
\hspace{0.5in} Enter your acknowledgement text here.
\clearpage


\tableofcontents*  
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\cftlocalchange{toc}{400pt}{0cm}% change settings to suppress dots
\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{CHAPTER}{}% add word "CHAPTER"
\cftlocalchange{toc}{1.55em}{2.55em}% restore original settings %\cftlocalchange{toc}{1.55em}{2.55em}% restore original settings

\newpage

%\newpage
%\chapter*{List of Symbols\hfill} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF      
SYMBOLS/NOMENCLATURE}
%\listofsymbols


\pagestyle{plain}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{14}

\clearpage
\newpage

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{asu}

\setcounter{page}{1} \pagenumbering{arabic} %
\setcounter{table}{0}

\pagestyle{plain}


\chapter{Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section} 
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsection{This is a subsection}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{This is a section} 
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section} 
\subsection{This is a subsection}

\chapter{Chapter} 

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsection{This is a subsection} 

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{This is a section} 
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\section{This is a section} 
\section{This is a section} 
\section{This is a section}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsection{This is a subsection}
\subsection{This is a subsection}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section}
\section{This is a section} 

\chapter{Chapter}


\end{document}
```

**The pwasu.sty file:**

```
% pwasu.sty  ASU theses/dissertations
% brief instructions at the beginning
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Usage:
% ============================
% A template for a thesis is provided in the file 'asthesis.tex',
% available from the same place where you obtained this file.
%
% In the following I will introduce some commands defined:
% ============================
% \settitle               % title of dissertation.
% \setauthor              % author of dissertation.
% \masters                % use if going for a Masters degree
% \doctors                % use if going for a PhD
% \setdefdate             % defence date
% \setgraddate            % graduation date
% \setchair               % committee chair
% \setmembers             % committee members
% \setdedication          % set dedication
% \asuabstract            % abstract
% \asuacknowledgements    % acknowledgements
% \biosketch              % biographical
%=============================
%
% With all the names, you are ready to start your journey
% I will show you how.
% Roll down, skip all the definitions.
% Find a session that starts with 'Here it is!'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{pwasu}[2009/04/18 v0.3 ASU thesis]
%% Only works with the memoir class!
\@ifclassloaded{memoir}{\let\endpwasu\relax}{\let\endpwasu\endinput
  \PackageError{pwasu}{The pwasu package only works with the memoir class}{\@ehd}}
\endpwasu
% Some useful lengths for layout purposes
\newlength{\toptafiddle}
\newlength{\bottafiddle}
\newlength{\topfiddle}
\newlength{\botfiddle}
\newlength{\linespace}

%% set up margins, assuming letterpaper (8.5 by 11) stock
% left, right and textwidth
\setlrmarginsandblock{1.375in}{1.375in}{*}

%% for main body
%% bottom of text at 1in, footer below
%% top of header at 1in, first text line double spaced below base of header
\setlength{\linespace}{\baselineskip} %% the current equivalent of \onelineskip
\setlength{\headheight}{\lineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{\linespace}
\addtolength{\headsep}{-\topskip}
\setlength{\uppermargin}{2in}
\addtolength{\uppermargin}{\headheight}
\addtolength{\uppermargin}{\headsep}
\setlength{\lowermargin}{2in}  %  This number was changed from 2in to 3in
\setlength{\footskip}{\onelineskip}  % This looks like it may set the lower margin and was changed from "\onelineskip" to 2in
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\uppermargin}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\lowermargin}
%% the fiddle lengths (..ta.. for title/approval page, others for prelims)
%% (determined by many trials and errors)
\setlength{\toptafiddle}{1\linespace}
\setlength{\topfiddle}{\toptafiddle}
\setlength{\bottafiddle}{\onelineskip}
\setlength{\botfiddle}{0pt} % actually this is not used

\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% pagestyles
%% the main text
\makepagestyle{asu}
  %\makeevenhead{asu}{\thepage}{}{}
  %\makeoddhead{asu}{}{}{\thepage}

%% for continuation pages of the ToC, LoF, LoT, LoS
\makepagestyle{toc}
  \makeevenfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddfoot{toc}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeevenhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}  %  The name "CHAPTER" should be made uppercase to match the ASU style
  \makeoddhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}  %  The name "CHAPTER" should be made uppercase to match the ASU style
  \DoubleSpacing

\makepagestyle{lof}
  \makeevenfoot{lof}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddfoot{lof}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeevenhead{lof}{Figure}{}{Page}
  \makeoddhead{lof}{Figure}{}{Page}

\makepagestyle{lot}
  \makeevenfoot{lot}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeoddfoot{lot}{}{\thepage}{}
  \makeevenhead{lot}{Table}{}{Page}
  \makeoddhead{lot}{Table}{}{Page}

%% use pagestyle{plain} for prelims

%% chapter style
\makechapterstyle{asu}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip} {-1\topfiddle}
\setlength{\afterchapskip} {\onelineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-0.4in}  %  Changed from -0.4in to -3.4in
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{3pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\normalfont}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\centering\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}
}
%% chapter style for appendices, text comes on following page
\makechapterstyle{asuappendix}{%
\setlength{\beforechapskip}{-\topfiddle}
\setlength{\afterchapskip}{1\onelineskip}
  \setlength{\beforechapskip}{-0.4in}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{0pt}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnamefont}{\MakeUppercase}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\chapnamefont}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{\centering\chapnumfont \thechapter}
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\centering}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternonum}{plain}
  \renewcommand*{\afterchaptertitle}{\clearpage}
}
%\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{asu}

%%% different chapter style for appendices, (and double spaced?)

\let\oldapp\appendix
%%\renewcommand*{\appendix}{\oldapp\chapterstyle{asuappendix}\DoubleSpace}

%%% (subsub)section styles
%\setlength{\beforesecskip}{\onelineskip}
\setsecheadstyle{\centering\normalfont\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setsubsecheadstyle{\centering\itshape\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setsubsubsecheadstyle{\centering\vspace*{-\onelineskip}}
\setlength{\aftersecskip}{3pt}

%%%% Do the ToC
\let\oldtoc\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{\clearpage\pagestyle{toc}\oldtoc}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand*{\tocheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}  %  This controls the space between the top of the page and the text "TABLE OF CONTENTS"
\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak \mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}\par\nobreak}

%\renewcommand*{\aftertoctitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}\par\nobreak\mbox{}\hfill{\MakeUppercase Chapter}\par\nobreak}



\renewcommand*{\cftchapterfont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterpagefont}{\normalfont}
%\renewcommand*{\cftchapterleader}{%
%  \cftchapterfont\cftdotfill{\cftchapterdotsep}}
\renewcommand*{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}
%\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{CHAPTER~}  %  this was commented out
%%% no extra space before the entry
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{0pt plus 0pt}
%% no extra 'chapter' space in LoF/LoT
\renewcommand*{\insertchapterspace}{}

\makeevenhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}

\makeoddhead{toc}{CHAPTER}{}{Page}


%% And the LoF and LoT
\let\oldlof\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\clearpage\pagestyle{lof}\oldlof}
\renewcommand*{\lofheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}  %  Changed from -\topfiddle
\renewcommand*{\afterloftitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak {\normalfont Figure \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}

\let\oldlot\listoftables
\renewcommand{\listoftables}{\clearpage\pagestyle{lot}\oldlot}
\renewcommand*{\lotheadstart}{\vspace*{-\topfiddle}}   %  Changed from -\topfiddle
\renewcommand*{\afterlottitle}{\thispagestyle{plain}%
  \par\nobreak {\normalfont Table \hfill Page}\par\nobreak}

%%% general macro for Abstract, etc., headings
\newcommand*{\pretoctitle}[1]{{\clearpage\centering \vspace*{-\topfiddle}#1\par}} %  Changed from -\topfiddle

%%% Start the ABSTRACT
\newcommand{\asuabstract}{\pretoctitle{ABSTRACT}}

%% make it easy to center any dedication
\newcommand{\setdedication}[1]{\def\asudedication{{\clearpage\mbox{}\vfill\centering #1 \par\vfill\clearpage}}}
\setdedication{}
%\setdedication{All for my parrot}

%%% Start the ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS
\newcommand{\asuacknowledgements}{\pretoctitle{ACKNOWLEDGEMENTS}}

%% for any headings after the tocloft and before the main body
\newcommand{\prelimtitle}[1]{\pretoctitle{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}
%% for REFERENCE section
\renewcommand*{\bibname}{REFERENCES}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\onelineskip}

%%% put your biographical text in this environment
%% \begin{biosketch} Im a person who has accomplished .... \end{biosketch}
%\newenvironment{biosketch}{%
%  \pretoctitle{BIOGRAPHICAL SKETCH}\thispagestyle{plain}\SingleSpacing}%
%  {}

%% for the title page and approval page.
\newcommand{\settitle}[1]{\def\asutitle{#1}}  % your title
\newcommand{\setauthor}[1]{\def\asuauthor{#1}} % you
\newcommand{\setdoctype}[1]{\def\asudoctype{#1}} % document type (e.g., thesis)
\newcommand{\masters}{\def\asudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}}
\newcommand{\doctors}{\def\asudegree{Doctor of Philosophy}}
\newcommand{\setdefdate}[1]{\def\asudefdate{#1}} % defense date
\newcommand{\setgraddate}[1]{\def\asugraddate{#1}} % graduation date
\newcommand{\setchair}[1]{\def\asuchair{#1, Chair}} % Committee chair
\newcommand{\setchairs}[2]{\def\asuchair{#1, Co-Chair \\ #2, Co-Chair}} %Co-Chairs
\newcommand{\setmembers}[1]{\def\asumembers{#1\par}} % the other committee members

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%'Here it is!'
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Use them like this, and if you dont use them then you will
% get unacceptable title and/or approval pages
%
% Change this part for your own title

\settitle{Thesis Title}

% Change this part for you name
\setauthor{Author Name Goes Here}
\setdoctype{Dissertation}

% comment out the part you dont need using '%' and free the part you need

%%\masters  % going for a Masters degree
\doctors % going for a PhD

% set your date
\setdefdate{August 2013}

% set your graduation date
\setgraddate{December 2013}
% who is your chair
\setchair{Chair Name}

% and members
\setmembers{{Member One Name} \\ {Member Two Name} \\ {Member Three Name} \\ {Member Four Name}}

% \setmembers{{example} \ {example}}
%
% your dedication
%\setdedication{Dedicatee}
%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% typesets the TITLE page
\newcommand{\thetitlepage}{{%
\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
\centering
\vspace*{-\toptafiddle}
\asutitle \\ by \\ \asuauthor
\linebreak
\linebreak

{\SingleSpace
A \asudoctype\ Presented in Partial Fulfillment \\
of the Requirements for the Degree \\
\asudegree\par
}

\vfill
{\SingleSpacing
Approved \asudefdate\ by the \\
Graduate Supervisory Committee: \\[-0.5\onelineskip]
{\SingleSpacing
\asuchair \\
\asumembers}
}

\vfill
ARIZONA STATE UNIVERSITY \\
\asugraddate
\enlargethispage{\bottafiddle}
\clearpage}}

%%% typesets the APPROVAL page
%%\newcommand{\approvalpage}{{%
%%\pagestyle{empty}
%%\centering
%%\vspace*{-\toptafiddle}
%%\asutitle \\ by \\ \asuauthor \\[3\onelineskip]
%%has been approved \\
%%\asudefdate

%%\vfill

%%Graduate Supervisory Committee: \\[-0.5\onelineskip]
%%{\SingleSpacing
%%\asuchair \\
%%\asumembers}

% you don't want to say that before it actually is.
%%\vfill
%%ACCEPTED BY THE GRADUATE COLLEGE
%%\enlargethispage{\bottafiddle}
%%\clearpage}}

%% use the asu chapterstyle
\chapterstyle{asu}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% end of *.sty file
\endinput
```

Comment: Is this the same question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122657/how-to-indent-chapter-headings-in-a-toc-memoir-class

Comment: No, there are two problems with the same code.  I posted two questions because I have two problems.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but is there any chance you can turn this into an MWE? (I'm going to assume pwasu.sty is immutable, so that can stay as-is if you like.)